# how to set border style of a UITextfield

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How can I set the border style of a `UITextField` programatically?

I am creating my text field like so:

```
UITextField *tfText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 200, 200, 30)];
tfText.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.9 blue:0.5 alpha:0.3];       
tfText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:tfText];
[tfText release];
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try this

```
UITextField *tfText = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65, 200, 200, 30)];
tfText.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.9 blue:0.5 alpha:0.3];       
tfText.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
// Border Style None
[tfText setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[self.view addSubview:tfText];
[tfText release];
```

For Reference

- http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/01/04/uitextfield-a-complete-api-overview/

Answer (score 8):

You can use Quartzcore and the layer properties.

```
sometextfield.layer.borderWidth = 1;
sometextfield.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
```

I must remember to add QuartzCore to your project and to import it where you want to use it.

Answer (score 6):

*From below four, anyone can be used programatically,*

```
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];

[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleLine];

[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];

[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
```

where **textField** is an outlet of **UITextField**

Answer (score 4):

I know, the question is about Obj-C, but i came here for Swift. And in Swift, it's done like that:

```
txt.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0);
txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
let myColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0);
txt.layer.borderWidth = 3;
txt.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor;
```

This sets a custom background color and a border in the same color (to hide the border but still have some padding between text and the textfield borders.

Answer (score 2):

```c
[pTxtTithiTime.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];

[pTxtTithiTime.layer setBorderWidth:0.8];
```

**//The rounded corner part, where you specify your view's corner radius:**

```c
  pTxtTithiTime.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

  pTxtTithiTime.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make UITextField Programmatically like this:

```
UITextField *txtField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 260, 280, 30)]; // your required coordinate
txtField.delegate =        self;
txtField.placeholder =     @"My TextField";
txtField.borderStyle =      UITextBorderStyleNone;
txtField.keyboardType =        UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
txtField.backgroundColor =       [self setBackGroundColorOnButton];
txtField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
```