# Cannot remove border of UITextField dynamically

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to remove the border of UITextField dynamically.

I tried `[stringTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];`

but nothing happened. Any idea?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789816/how-to-set-border-style-of-a-uitextfield

Comment: Is there a chance you’re not on the main thread when you’re calling this? If it’s a network callback or other async method, you will need to `dispatch_async()` to the main queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the `TextField` already displayed in the view when this happens? If so, you (probably) need to execute the following:

```
[stringTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[stringTextField setNeedsDisplay];
```

in order for the view to redraw the `TextField`, sans border. Note that there's no guarantee the system will immediately redraw the `textField`. You're indicating to the system that you'd like the field to be redrawn.

Comment: I did what you said. If I do UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect, it is ok. But if I write UITextBorderStyleNone, nothing happens

Comment: Actually for UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect, no need to setNeedsDisplay.

Answer (score 4):

With an existing UITextField I found that this worked:

```
[textField setEnabled:NO];
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
```

while this did not (the border remained in the view):

```
[textField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[textField setEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Spent a good 45 minutes before this made everything work. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ones.

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```