# How to remove border of UITextField in navigationbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar

I want to remove UItextField Border which is in navigationbar. I've gone through this link, but it is not working. (I made a sample app and added UItextField on ViewConroller so it is working fine)

[How to hide UITextField border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116471/how-to-hide-uitextfield-border)

[Cannot remove border of UITextField dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319377/cannot-remove-border-of-uitextfield-dynamically)

Comment: did you try `textfield.layer.borderWidth = 0`

Comment: Yes but border still display.

Comment: Post your UI screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove the border of UITextView or UITextField? 
If you want to remove it in a textField just try this:

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    textField = subview as! UITextField
    textField.borderStyle = .None
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = 14
    textField.background = nil;
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```