# Is there a way to change the whole background color of a UITextField of a UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertcontroller, uibackgroundcolor

I'm trying to change the background color of a UITextField of a UIAlertController.

**First, I added the UITextField using this code:**

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *tfPrompt) {
    self.textField = tfPrompt;
}];
```

**After, in another moment, I tried to change it's background color using this code:**

```
[self.textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

**But this is what I got:**

[image]

What I really want is to fill the whole background of this UITextField. **Is this possible?** Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote the wrong code here. I updated my answer.

Comment: may be the textfield is present in a uiview, you should try to find that view and chage its background color too.

Comment: [use this lib... its awesome](https://github.com/Darktt/DTAlertView)

Comment: Thanks, @TejaNandamuri! I tried your sugestion and I checked that other question. It worked!

Comment: And thanks for all others that tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the `UITextField`'s `borderStyle` attribute.

You can refer to this thread: [how to set border style of a UITextfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789816/how-to-set-border-style-of-a-uitextfield).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but what I needed to do was set the background color of UITextField's superview.